# Use Azure Go SDK to enumerate app credentials

Tags: azure-sdk, azure-sdk-for-go, azure-sdk-go

I'm new to Azure and struggling to generate the Go code that's equivalent to `az ad app credential list --id=${ID}`.

I find the Azure Go SDK to be comprehensive but the documentation is lacking. Is there a general-purpose mechanism by which I can determine the Go SDK from an `az` command?

**Update** So, it appears the [`services`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services@v68.0.0+incompatible#pkg-overview) package (containing `services/graphrbac`) is deprecated and that `azidentity` is the preferred auth package. And I can continue to use `azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential`

But, I'm still unable to determine the Go package that matches `az ad app credential list`.

<strike>I asked ChatGPT and it gave me something (non-working) that uses the Graph RBAC API with which I'm entirely unfamiliar</strike>

I have known-working code that uses `azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)` to authenticate using both the CLI's credentials and a certificate and, would like to stick with this familiar (powerful) mechanism if possible.

It's unclear to me whether [`secretClient.ListKeyCredentials`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go@v68.0.0+incompatible/services/graphrbac/1.6/graphrbac#ServicePrincipalsClient.ListKeyCredentials) is even the correct package/method that I need to use.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Which of the two tags is correct? `azure-sdk-for-go` or `azure-sdk-go`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the [ListPasswordCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go@v68.0.0+incompatible/services/graphrbac/1.6/graphrbac#ApplicationsClient.ListPasswordCredentials) function from the [graphrbac](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go@v68.0.0+incompatible/services/graphrbac/1.6/graphrbac#ApplicationsClient.ListPasswordCredentials) go package to fetch the passwordCredentials associated with an application. Please update the below sample code:

```
    client:= graphrbac.NewApplicationsClient(tenantID)
    client.Authorizer = graphAuth

    // Call the ListPasswordCredentials method to get a list of password credentials for the specified application object ID

    list, err := client.ListPasswordCredentials(appObjID)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Iterate over the list of password credentials and print the properties of each credential
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I think `ListPasswordCredentials` isn't the correct method.

Comment: The AzCLI command `az ad app credential list` lists an application's (AppID's) password or certificate credential metadata.

`ListPasswordCredentials` helps to get the passwordCredentials associated with an application (App ID).

Please let me know the issue you are facing while using the above sample.

Comment: I learned subsequently that the `services` module is deprecated. Because, I'm unfamiliar with these SDKs, I'd prefer not to spend time working with the quirks of authorizers and would prefer to use the `sdk` packages.